# Creating Custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler and calling default AuthenticationSuccessHandler when done

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, groovy

i want to create `CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler` to add log to each user login:

```
class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    UserService getUserService() {
        return ApplicationContextHolder.getBean('userService')
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res, Authentication auth) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        userService.postLoginMessage(auth.principal.username, null)

    }
}
```

it's simple enough code and works well, but now i have no return value. is there a way to call the default `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` after my custom code run or to return default value?

I mean to return the `Authentication` json.

Comment: What version of grails was this?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong essentially.

Instead of overriding the success handler, you should register an event listener.

Config:
`grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true`

Register a class as a bean

```
class MySecurityEventListener
      implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService

    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
userService.postLoginMessage(event.authentication.principal.username, null)
    }
}
```